# Problem with USB booting media test failure

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to install windows 10 in my ubuntu pc(not dual boot). When I am creating a bootable USB with some linux distribution, I am being easily able to boot from the USB. But if I make that same USB bootable with windows 10(using same software), an error is coming "Media Test Failure Check Cable Exiting PXE ROM" while trying to boot from the USB directly from BIOS. My pc has a whole linux drive with no partition. What might be causing it?

Comment: Not actually, I am making both in linux environment.

Comment: Which software are you using to make the bootable USB?  Linux usually has problems making a bootable USB with Win 10 except for a couple of softwares.

Comment: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can create an installer drive for Windows 10 in Ubuntu. -- The standard cloning method, that works with most Linux iso files does not work with Windows 10. You need a special method or tool for that purpose.